# Restangular - getList in response

Tags: angularjs, api, restangular

can you say me what I am do wrong ?

```
var api = Restangular.all('person');
api.getList().then(function(data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function(val,key) {
       val.getList('role').then(function(res) {
           //...
       });
 });});
```

I want call */person/:id/role* , but now call */person/role* ...

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @min che , now is working good.

Solution: in *angular.run()*

```
Restangular.configuration.getIdFromElem = function(elem) {
        // if route is person ==> returns idPerson
        return elem["id"+elem.route.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + elem.route.slice(1)];
    }
```

Code on restangular page -> [here](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#what-if-each-of-my-models-has-a-different-id-name-like-customerid-for-customer) ... which use RestangularProvider in *angular.config()* not working for me

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get a person by it's id, you should use Restangular.one('person', person.id) which will create /person/:id/

Comment: Yes I know, but I want get all person and for every person get also his roles ..
 on Restangular pages is example ... 
`var firstAccount = accounts[0];
  // This will query /accounts/123/buildings considering 123 is the id of the firstAccount
  $scope.buildings = firstAccount.getList("buildings");
`
so I except something similar ...

Comment: can you post the first element of data?
I've just tried your code, and it works with my data, so another thing seems to be the issue.

Comment: No, i must create new object by .one() ... So where can be problem , something in config ?

Comment: Have you checked the data you're receiving in the response? This seems like you're either not receiving data, or your data has no id in it...
Are you sure that the you shouldn't do Restangular.all('persons')? (plural)

Comment: I got data, only my data have not identificator just ID ... But identificator string is idPerson ... I dont know if i  must do some config for recognize ID field